# When should Doctrine filters be disabled in the SonataAdmin workflow?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm sure this is a common ask, I need softdeletable and similar filters off in SonataAdmin, until now I've been doing:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin as BaseAdmin;

class Admin extends BaseAdmin
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        /**
         * This executes everywhere in the admin and disables softdelete for everything, if you need something cleverer this should be rethought.
         */
        $filters = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->getFilters();

        if (array_key_exists('approvable', $filters->getEnabledFilters())) {
            $filters->disable('approvable');
        }

        if (array_key_exists('softdeleteable', $filters->getEnabledFilters())) {
            $filters->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
    }
}
```

Which causes a number of problems, one, it needs the conditionals because the admin classes are configured twice, once to build the nav, and again to build interfaces, two, the admin classes are instantiated frontend on a cold (APC maybe?) cache, which is pretty uncool.

Where are you meant to put this logic?

Comment: I haven't worked on this project recently, but I believe I could probably achieve this by adding a custom admin controller for the applicable admin. Additionally, it is now possible to disable filters for a particular entity, which would probably be a better plan than globally disabling them.

Comment: Any code example for disabling filters for a particular entity, @Steve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Event Listener. For example:

Service:

```
filter.configurator:
class: AppBundle\Filter\Configurator
arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
```

Listener class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CoreController;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\HelperController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

/**
 * Class Configurator
 *
 * @author Andrey Nilov <nilov@glavweb.ru>
 */
class Configurator
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * onKernelRequest
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        $controllerClass = $controller[0];

        $isAdminController =
            $controllerClass instanceof CRUDController ||
            $controllerClass instanceof CoreController ||
            $controllerClass instanceof HelperController
        ;

        if ($isAdminController) {
            $this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
    }
}
```